# Optimal search query and structure for querying large set of data

Tags: mysql, performance, full-text-search, sql-like

I've created file indexer which simply inserts filenames into specified table. Now I'm considering the best way to search for the filenames. There could be 100000+ files in table so performance is important.

File name can be various - 10, 20, 50 or more characters in length. At least for now, my test dataset has no files with spaces in their names. User can do partial search, for example looking for '1001' should return file with name 10_1001_20_30_40_50.

My current table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `file` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_category` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file_ext` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`id_category`),
  KEY `idx_file_filename` (`filename`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `fk_file_1_idx` (`id_category`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `filename` (`filename`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=24974 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `file` (`id`,`id_category`,`filename`,`file_ext`,`date_added`) VALUES (22474,14199,'095_98_1002_1003_148_98_1001_003','pdf','2016-03-19 19:02:12');
INSERT INTO `file` (`id`,`id_category`,`filename`,`file_ext`,`date_added`) VALUES (22475,14199,'095_98_1002_1003_148_98_1001_001','pdf','2016-03-19 19:02:11');
```

I've tried to use MATCH () AGAINST (), but it turned out it's not a good idea if you don't have spaces in string and want to do "if string contains search" like:

```
SELECT id, filename FROM `file` WHERE MATCH(filename) AGAINST ('1002*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This is not going to return what I need. What I'm considering is to use FULLTEXT by split all filenames while importing into 3 length (min. string length user can provide) parts separated by spaces and them use queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `file` WHERE MATCH(filename) AGAINST ('100*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Of course I can leave filenames as they are and use LIKE operator:

```
SELECT * FROM `file` WHERE filename LIKE '%100%'
```

but there is a lot negative opinions about using LIKE for large data sets. I'm curious if my solution with adding spaces to file names will be a good idea.

Comment: Ale You looking for 1002 only, or You like to search longer sequences (1002_1003) too?

Comment: It could be any query >= 3 characters

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to use FULLTEXT:  requires space, limits you (mostly) to full "words", gets inefficient with "short" words, misses "stop words", etc.

`LIKE '%100%`', though inefficient because it must test every row, is what you need.

You imply that all the relevant parts of the filenames are numbers?  And that you only want to test for whole parts?  That is `22_100_33` will be searched for `22`, `100`, and `33`, but not for `2`, `10`, `00`, etc??  If all that is the case, then `LIKE` will not work correctly.  Example:  `101_1000` will be caught by `LIKE '%100%`'.

So, *maybe* you want to build an "inverted index":  For `10_1001_20_30_40_50`, you would have a 6 rows in a table:  `10`, `1001`, etc, and either the rest of the columns, or some id(s) for joining to the `file` table.

Comment: Thanks for clearing case with FT. I will test for parts and I need parts back so LIKE is OK. Filenames and parts within them can be alphanumeric, various length so I can't use inverted index structure you proposed. Question is still open - for now looks like I have to use LIKE.

Answer (score 0):

> there is a lot negative opinions about using LIKE for large data sets

Chances are it would be good enough for Your case, I would test it first.

If You really want to speed it up, I can think of one option, but sacrifices would be huge - memory, insertion times, maintanability, flexibility, complexity... You can build "inverted index" for suffixes. The table would look like (pseudocode):

```
CREATE TABLE Pref(
    prefix varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    fileid bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_Pref] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    prefix ASC,
    fileid ASC
))
```

and have data like this

```
'095_98_1002_1003_148_98_1001_003', 22474
'95_98_1002_1003_148_98_1001_003', 22474
'5_98_1002_1003_148_98_1001_003', 22474
'_98_1002_1003_148_98_1001_003', 22474
'98_1002_1003_148_98_1001_003', 22474
...
'03', 22474
'3', 22474
```

it would have clustered primary key on both columns. That way it would be ordered by the prefix and you can change infix search `'%abcd%'` into prefix search `'abcd%'`. The query would then have the form

```
SELECT id, filename FROM `file` 
WHERE id IN (SELECT fileid FROM Pref WHERE prefix like 'abcd%')
```

You just have to make triggers to keep it in sync with the main table. Beware, that when You delete the row in this table, You should avoid search of fileid without prefix specified, or the performance would be a disaster.